# $expr arrayElementAt not working in aggregation for embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I am doing mongo db aggregation like

```
$cursor = $this->collection->aggregate(
            array(
                array(
                    '$project' => array(
                        'FullName' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                        'FirstMiddle' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$middle_name')),
                        'FirstLast' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                        'FirstName' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name')),
                        'MiddleName' => array('$concat' => array('$middle_name')),
                        'LastName' => array('$concat' => array('$last_name')),
                        'Student' => '$$ROOT'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '$match' =>
                    array(
                        '$or' => array(
                            array("FullName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("FirstLast" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("FirstMiddle" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("FirstName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("MiddleName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("LastName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                            array("Student.registration_temp_perm_no" => $arg),
                           '$expr' => array(
                               '$eq'=> array(
                                     array('$arrayElemAt' => array('$allotment_details.room_id', -1)), $this->RoomId)),
                        ),
                       // "Student.assigned_keys" => ['$exists' => false],
                        "Student.schoolId" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->SchoolId)
                    )
                )
            )
 );
```

I have collection which contains data like

```
"first_name": "John",
"middle_name": "",
"last_name": "Mayor",
"allotment_details": [
 {
    "allotment_id": "ff666d55-2fcc-79b2-e4da-e165939555bb",
    "room_id": "5be2d9aad2ccda0fdc006a65",
    "bay_id": ObjectId("5be2d9aad2ccda0fdc006a61"),
     ...
}
```

The above code is working for fine concatenation of three names types and searching all the data passed in `$arg`. Note that I have added  `array('$arrayElemAt' => array('$allotment_details.room_id', -1)), $this->RoomId))` in order to fetch students based on concatenation of names and those students should be fetched on the basis of `$this->RoomId`.

The above code is not fetching students assigned to a room but is fetching all the students based on concatenation of names.
Please help !!!

Comment: `allotment_details` is not included in your initial `$project`, so the field is not there. `$project` and `$group` only return the fields you "explicitly" name. You should not be doing this anyway. If you need to match the "last" array element, then you should be "reversing your array" in storage instead. Then simply match on the regular query 'allotment_details.0.room_id' since your "reversed" array last the newest added item "first".

Comment: At any rate `$match` should pretty much always be the very first aggreation pipeline stage. Also the query is not really smart in general, and you really should be using `$or` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: can you please provide code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick fix

Your "pipeline" does not work here *primarily* because your initial [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) lacks the field you want to use an a later stage. The *"quick fix"* is therefore basically to include that field in the "projected" document, since that's how aggregation pipeline stages work:

```
array(
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      'FullName' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
      'FirstMiddle' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$middle_name')),
      'FirstLast' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
      'FirstName' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name')),
      'MiddleName' => array('$concat' => array('$middle_name')),
      'LastName' => array('$concat' => array('$last_name')),
      'Student' => '$$ROOT',
      'allotment_details' => 1 # that's the change
    )
  ),
```

Or even since you used `$$ROOT` for `Student` anyway, simply qualify the field under that path:

```
'$expr' => array(
  '$eq'=> array(
    array('$arrayElemAt' => array('$Student.allotment_details.room_id', -1)),
    $this->RoomId
  )
),
```

***however*** I would **strongly*** implore that you do **NOT** do that.

The whole concept of "concatenating strings" in order to do a later [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the content is a really bad idea since it means the whole collection gets rewritten in the pipeline before any "filtering" actually gets done.

Likewise looking to match on the "last" array element is also an issue. A far better approach is to instead actually add "new items" to the "beginning" of the array, instead of the "end". This is actually what the [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) or possibly even the `$sort` modifiers to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) do for you, by changing where items get added or the sorted order of items respectively.

### Changing the Array to "newest first"

This takes a little work by changing the way you store things, but the benefits are greatly improved speed of such queries like you want without needing an evaluated `$expr` argument.

The core concepts are to "pre-pend" new array items with syntax like:

```
$this->collection->updateOne(
  $query,
  [ '$push' => [ 'allotment_details' => [ '$each' => $allotments, '$position' => 0 ] ] ]
)
```

Where `$alloments` **must** be an array as required by [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) and [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) is used to `0` in order to add the new array item "first".

Alternately if you actually have something like `created_date` as a property within each of the objects in the array, then you "could" use something like [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) as a modifier instead.

```
$this->collection->updateOne(
  $query,
  [ '$push' => [
      'allotment_details' => [ '$each' => $allotments, '$sort' => [ 'created_date' => -1 ] ]
  ]]
)
```

It really depends on whether your "query" and other access requirements rely on "last added" or "latest date", and then also typically if you intend to possibly alter such a `created_date` or other "sort" property in a way which would effect the order of the array elements when "sorted".

The reason you do this is then matching the "latest" ( which is now the "first" ) item in the array simply becomes:

```
$this->collection->find([
 'allotment_details.0.room_id': $this->RoomId
])
```

MongoDB allows the "first" array index to be specified with ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation), using the `0` index. What you **cannot** do is specify a "negative" index i.e:

```
$this->collection->find([
 'allotment_details.-1.room_id': $this->RoomId  # not allowed :(
])
```

That's the reason why you do the things shown above on "update" in order to "re-order" your array to the workable form.

### Concatenation is Bad

The other main issue is the concatenation of strings. As already mentioned this creates unnecessary overhead just in order to do the matching you want. It's also "unnecessary" since you can complete avoid this using `$or` with the conditions on each of the fields as they exist already within the actual document:

```
 $this->collection->find([
   '$or' => [
       [ 'first_name' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i') ],
       [ 'last_name' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i') ],
       [ 'middle_name' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i') ],
       [ 'registration_temp_perm_no' => $arg ]
   ],
   'schoolId' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->SchoolId),
   'allotment_details.0.room_id': $this->RoomId
 ])
```

And of course whatever the "full" query conditions actually need to be, but you should be getting the basic idea.

Also if you are not actually looking for "partial words", then a ["text search"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) defined over the fields with the "names". After creating the index that would be:

```
 $this->collection->find([
   '$text' => [ '$search' => $arg ],
   'schoolId' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->SchoolId),
   'allotment_details.0.room_id': $this->RoomId
 ])
```

---

Overall I would really recommend looking closely at all the other options rather than making one small change to your existing code. With a little careful re-structuring of how you store things and indeed "index" things, you get huge performance benefits that your extensive `$concat` "brute force" approach simply cannot deliver.

> **N.B** Modern PHP Releases generally support `[]` as a much more brief representation of `array()`. It's a lot cleaner and far easier to read. So please use it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort u have put to answer my question